# SQL Performance in Memory (join vs. loop)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join

I had a really stiring discussion with one of my coworkers about Joins in SQL (more mysql). I couldn't believe that I should evade Joins at all costs, because a Join with a big Table will load the whole Table into the Memory of a Server and will therefore fill the Memory with lots of Data. But If I use a simple query without a join and a loop it will be a better performance for Memory and processing speed. For Example (its more Pseudocode and PHP):

> size of the Tables:
>
> - user: 30 mb
> - action: 20kb

1. Code (with Join)

   ```
   $actionArray = sql_stmt(SELECT action.rating, user.username FROM user INNER JOIN action on user.id = action.id WHERE action.id = 1)

   $endresult[] = $actionArray
   ```
2. Code (without Join and foreach-loop)

   ```
   $actionArray = sql_stmt(SELECT * FROM action WHERE id = 1);

   foreach (actionArray as $row) {

      $user = sql_stmt(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $row['userid'];
      $endResult['rating'] = $row['rating'];
      $endResult['username'] = $user['username'];

   }
   ```

The results are the same but I have to choose the second option, because in my Company we are not allowed to use joins (see Explantion above) and not only in my littel advertising agency, even in bigger companys (50 - 100 employees or in online gaming development) they are not using joins!

Is this a thing companys (especially for websites) do? Screw on joins because 1000 visitors of a website at the same time could overflow the servers memory?

I could not believe this argumentation. Isn't a faster execution of the Code much better than looping over all necessary data?

Comment: JOINs are generally (although not always) more efficient than doing individual queries in a loop, because there is an overhead for every individual query.... and JOINS don't load the whole table into memory, code that uses functions like fetchall() does that

Comment: hmm, sorry if I question your answer, but isn't the function fetchall(), fetch() oder fetchcolumn() suppose to give the results of an executed querry from the database? I mean, why should this functions load a whole table into his memory while the execution of the query held in the database. fetch(), fetchall(), ...  are only collecting the given resultset of rows.

Comment: `fetch()` fetches a single record from the resultset at a time into PHP memory, allowing you to process that record however you will, then move on and `fetch()` the next record.... you only have one database record at a time in PHP memory.... `fetchall()` pulls every record (that''s what the "all" in the function name means) from the resultset into PHP memory at the same time.... so if you have 100 records in the resultset, `fetch()` allows you to have 1 record in PHP memory at a time, while `fetchall()` will load all 100 records into PHP memory, using 100x as much memory

Comment: It's not the `fetch` that is costly; it is the `SELECT` in the loop.